# PHP Format Name using Array e.g. John Smith to John S

Tags: php, arrays

`$data['full_name']` stores the full name e.g. John Smith

At the moment I am using

```
$data['full_name'] = strtok($data['full_name'], " ");
```

This will convert the first name for me -  E.g. John

I want to also include the second name - E.g. John S

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex replacement here:

```php
$input = "John Michael Smith";
$output = preg_replace("/(?<=\s)(\w)\w*/", "$1", $input);
echo $output;  // John M S
```

I used a regex pattern which will target all words in the name other than the first name and replace with just the first letter.  The regex pattern used here says to match:

```regex
(?<=\s)  assert that a space precedes (excludes the first name)
(\w)     match and capture the first letter
\w*      then consume the rest of the name, without matching
```

We replace with `$1`, which is just the first letter of the name component.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet

```
<?php

$input = "John Smith";
$name = explode(" ", $input);
$formatted = "";
foreach ($name as $key => $value)
{
    // code...
    if ($key == 0) {
        $formatted .= $value;
    } else {
        $formatted .= ' ' . substr($value, 0, 1);
    }
}

echo $formatted;
```

Comment: Perhaps add some comments as to why and how your solution solves the problem. Side note, I am formatting your code for you.